# How to disable checkbox with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I searched more time with it but it's not work, I want to checkbox is disabled, user not check and can check it if some condition. Ok, now, I tried disabled them. I use jquery 2.1.3

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value="U01" />Banana
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value="U02" />Orange
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value="U03" />Apple
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value="U04" />Candy
```

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#chk').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`id` should be unique. You cannot have four checkboxes with the same id.

You can try other selectors to select the whole range of checkboxes, like `.checkbox1` (by class), `input[type="checkbox"]` (by tag/attribute). Once you've fixed the ids, you could even try `#chk1, #chk2, #chk3, #chk4`.

The snippet below uses the classname 'chk' instead of the id 'chk'. Also, it uses `attr` to set the attribute although it did work for me using `prop` as well.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.chk').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U01" />Banana
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U02" />Orange
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U03" />Apple
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U04" />Candy
```

Comment: this will not work without disabled property defined

Comment: maybe it depends on browser

Comment: You removed the duplicate ID, so you could've done with `class="chk"`

Comment: That's right. I should remove `id="chk"` and use `class="chk"` . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You already changed the ID but you can also put the class in the same attribute such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1 chk" name="check[]" value="U01" />Banana
```

Then you can use jQuery to either disable or check a checkbox depending on you needs like so

To disable:

```
$(function () {
    $('.chk').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

To "precheck":

```
$(function () {
    $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
});
```

You can change the selector to fit IDs or classes even elements and change the properties between true or false according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U01" />Banana
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U02" />Orange
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U03" />Apple
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" class="chk" name="check[]" value="U04" />Candy
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(function() {
   $("input.checkbox1").prop("disabled", true);
});
```